# Dojo 1.4 parse time optimalization

Tags: javascript, dojo

We have project which can generate one single page with big amount of widgets (thousands). It takes a lot of time to load this page. 
Is there some specific option to improve **parse** time of dojo widgets?

**I'm not looking for load time of javascript**, which can be optimized with custom dojo build.

For example, page with 9200 widgets takes 28 seconds to parse.
(measured with dojo.parse.parse() and chrome developer tools timeline)

Any improvement and suggestions would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Still trying to work out why anyone would put 9,200 widgets in a single page. Anyway, I think this is off topic here.

Comment: Usually generated page (web form) has about 250 widgets including all buttons, dialogs etc. In very rare cases it has this big amount of widgets. Client of course wants everything on one page.

Comment: Is everything _required_ to be loaded initially? Can't you do something like parse (and create) the minimum number of widgets for a start and create as the user navigates?

Comment: Yes, i was thinking the same thing. User could scroll page down and dojo onShow event could trigger another widget initialization. BUT problem is that it will anyways consume same amount of time to initialization, and there is one nasty feature that client write its own javascript validation functions that have to run on form load. And we cant affect what there can be written